# how to remove navigationbar blur effect - swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

i searched a lot on internet but did not find any solution for the problem, i don't want the navigation bar to be blur as in the screenshot [image]

the colour of navigation bar does not match with the other colour even i have used the sam hex value for both. i want to fix it. please help

this is the code i am using to colour navigation bar

```
 let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 204/255.0, green: 51/255.0, blue: 51/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see isn't actually *blur effect*, but *translucent* style of `UINavigationBar`. If you don't want *translucent* bar, set its `isTranslucent` property to `false`

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this blur effect by using both standard and scroll edge

By Setting

```
       **Standard Appearance 
                background-color**
                This setting will Work to hide the blur effect on a scroll and also to set title style on scroll

       **Scroll Edge Appearance
                background-color**

                Appearance without scroll-like background color, title, etc.
```

Other Settings are remained the same like
Translucent: true etc

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use:

navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

Answer (score 0):

to remove blur effect add this code to your appDelegate,

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white, .font: UIFont(name: "SF-Pro", size: 17) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)]
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "main_bg_primary")
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
```

change the colours as your wish